# Creating a Redux Observable Epic with multiple API Calls - Passing the results of the first into the second

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, rxjs, redux-observable

This isn't the first time a question like this has been asked, but for some reason I'm having a real hard time wrapping my head around Observables and RxJs, so I thought I'd ask for some clarification.

I am trying to write an epic which will do the following:

1. Receive a string
2. Make an API call based on that string
3. Make three more (independent) API calls based on the results of the first, and write them into state.

I have read about `concatMap` and `forkJoin` which seem like they could be useful, as `concatMap` should allow me to execute multiple actions consecutively, and forkJoin becuase it can be used for returning the results of the final 3 API calls as a single array.

Here's some code to try and give an idea of what I want. Apologies for the repetitive question, but I'd be grateful for an answer.

```js
export const apiFetchEpic = (
  action$: any,
  state$: any,
  { apiClient }: IDependencies,
) =>
  action$.pipe(
    ofType(API_FETCH),
    debounce(() => timer(300)),
    withLatestFrom(state$),
    mergeMap(
      ([
        {
          payload: { config, uri },
        },
      ]: [{ payload: IApiFetchActionProps }, any]) => {
        return from(apiClient.get(uri, config)).pipe(
          mergeMap(res =>
            of(
              apiSetAction(res), // <-- I need the results of this to be passed into the next calls
              apiCompleteAction({ uri }),
            ),
          ),
          catchError(error =>
            of(apiCompleteAction({ uri }), apiErrorAction(error)),
          ),
        )
      },
    ),
  )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it like this:

```js
import { ofType, combineEpics } from 'redux-observable'
import {
  mergeMap,
  withLatestFrom,
  catchError,
  debounce,
  switchMap,
} from 'rxjs/operators'
import { from, of, timer, forkJoin } from 'rxjs'
import { IDependencies } from '../../configure-store'
import { apiErrorAction } from '../../reducers/errors/actions'
import {
  TOC_FETCH,
  tocSetAction,
  ITocFetchActionProps,
  tocCompleteAction,
} from '../../reducers/table-of-contents/actions'
import { defaults } from 'lodash'

// Can probably use forkJoin here, and create multiple API calls as a parallel observable
// https://github.com/patricktran/react-redux-observable-epic-forkjoin-apis/blob/master/src/epics/index.js

export const tocFetchEpic = (
  action$: any,
  state$: any,
  { apiClient }: IDependencies,
) => {
  return action$.pipe(
    ofType(TOC_FETCH),
    debounce(() => timer(300)), // anti-DDoS
    withLatestFrom(state$),
    mergeMap(
      ([
        {
          payload: { instance },
        },
      ]: [{ payload: ITocFetchActionProps }, any]) => {

        const params = { 'myParam': instance, limit: 1 }
        return from(apiClient.get('endpoint', { params })).pipe(
          mergeMap(
            (result): any => {

              const def = {
                limit: -1,
                'newParam': result.data.results[0],
              }
              const configurations = [
                {
                  uri: 'endpointOne',
                  config: defaults({}, def),
                },
                {
                  uri: 'endpointTwo',
                  config: defaults(
                    {
                      'specialParam': 'table',
                      'specialParamTwo': 'http://example.com',
                      'iso2:lang': 'en',
                    },
                    def,
                  ),
                },
                {
                  uri: 'endpointThree',
                  config: defaults(
                    {
                      'anotherSpecialParam': 'role',
                    },
                    def,
                  ),
                }, 
              ]

              // Create a bunch of observables
              const parallelObservables = configurations.map(api =>
                from(
                  apiClient.get(api.uri, { params: api.config }),
                ).pipe(
                  switchMap(response => of(response)),
                  catchError(err =>
                    of(apiErrorAction(err), tocCompleteAction({ instance })),
                  ),
                ),
              )

              // Return a forkJoin of them.
              return forkJoin(
                parallelObservables,
                (names: any, schoolNames: any, storeNames: any) => {
                  //projection
                  return { // <- The object returned here is ultimately what gets written into state
                    instance: result.data.results[0],
                    tables: names.data.results,
                    labels: [
                      ...schoolNames.data.results,
                      ...storeNames.data.results,
                    ],
                  }
                },
              ).pipe(
                switchMap(response => {
                  return of(
                    tocSetAction(response),
                    tocCompleteAction({ instance }),
                  )
                }),
              )
            },
          ),
          catchError(error =>
            of(tocCompleteAction({ instance }), apiErrorAction(error)),
          ),
        )
      },
    ),
  )
}

export default combineEpics(tocFetchEpic)
```